# Notifications for Site Updates

Tags: profile-page, discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

I noticed earlier this week that the user page of StackOverflow [and meta as well] had been been given a new look. Just last night, I opened my user page on my mobile device and saw that that one has been updated as well.

This was rather surprising as I've been reading the StackOverflow blog regularly and there wasn't any mention of the update.
I'm not saying the updates are bad. On the contrary, I think the new updates are very good and provide a one-stop overview of everything the user has done on the site. My argument is that we could do with some notification on the site blog so we're at least prepared for some changes.

Comment: [New User page - LIVE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112151)

Comment: Mh, now that I voted I'm suddenly not so sure about that anymore...But there's the blog and there's that question/answer...I think this should be sufficient, no?

Comment: This is not about just the recent change to the User Profile page. I'm advocating for prior notifications for *most* if not all changes that are implemented on SE.

Comment: `...prior notifications...` There was a prior notification here on Meta and not on the whole network. I guess the reason why only Meta-Users were notified was because we (the Meta crowd) have a deeper insight into the mechanics of the network, and can therefor easier spot problems, both in design and functionality. I see no reason to notify the whole network about changes, especially not if they're tested on Meta first.

Comment: Yup. If you're interested, you have to hang out here with us meta-heads...

Answer (score 1):

The notifications happened here on Meta:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112151

This is typical behavior. If you want a list of new features, a changelog if you will, Meta is a better bet than the blog:

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)